# I have a employees table and a tasks table (posgresql). I need to assign many tasks to one employee

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am trying to make a join table, with two columns, employee id and task ids. I select 5 tasks(Ids) and one employee on the client side, send an array of 5 task-Ids and an employee identifier to the server. But these 5 elements are not distributed in different lines.

I want such a result:

```
Employee_id  Task_id
   1            4
   1            3
   1            2
   1            1
   1            5
```

Node.js with Express.

Comment: So what result are you looking for, in SQL? Do you want a single record with all 5 taskids in an array? Please show us sample data as tabular text, and (the relevant parts of) your existing code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the task_list as an array then use the unroll function to break it into individual id.

```
insert into employee_task(empployee_id, task_id)
    select 1, unnest(array[4,3,2,1,5]);
```